# How to change com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver permission

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I use MobSF for the statistical analysis of my android app. It report this problem to me:

[image: MobSF report]

Can anyone tell me how the report can be resolved?

Comment: Can you post the whole of the `<receiver` tag from your manifest? (obfuscate your package name if it's there, obvs). Mine has `<intent-filter>` and `<category>` tags which may be the issue.